# Python - appending an element of list of lists into new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter

i'm seeking for help in solving one problem...

Let's assume i got a list:

```
list1 =[[1, 0, 2.83], [3, 1, 1.0], [5, 4, 2.83], [7, 0, 4.47], [6, 5, 4.24], [3, 2, 'x'], [4, 6, 'asd']
```

What i want to do is based on type of third element of inner lists, get filtered minimum value from these values, only if these are floats.

(It's totally fine if 3rd elements are same value, however i'm curious if that wont provide any exceptions - for me it would be the best if they would be picked even randomly)

Im trying something like this:

```
list1 = [[1, 0, 2.83], [3, 1, 1.0], [5, 4, 2.83], [7, 0, 4.47], [6, 5, 4.24], [3, 2, 'x'], [4, 6, 'asd']

something = min(filter(lambda x: x[2] is not isinstance(x[2], float) == True,list1))
```

... and by that im getting first element from that list which is: `[1, 0, 2.83]`, instead of `[3, 1, 1.0]` where the third element is lowest and is a float.

Comment: Where exactly does that expected `1.0` come from?

Comment: What is your desired output from the example posted?

Comment: Sorry, i'v put wrong value. My desired output of that list is `[3, 1, 1.0]` as `1.0` is the lowest from *third* elements out of *inner lists*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
something = min((x for x in list1 if isinstance(x[2], float)), key=lambda x: x[2])
```

By the way, IMHO the most suitable data structure for this kind of situation would be a `list` of `tuple`s, since they constitute heterogeneous collections of fixed size (in this case triples), like this:

```
list1 = [(1, 0, 2.83), (3, 1, 1.0), (5, 4, 2.83), (7, 0, 4.47), (6, 5, 4.24), (3, 2, 'x')]
```

Comment: Ok, thats solved my issue - I'll consider tuples. Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `min` function wrong - it is sorting using whole tuples (and the first value in the tuple rules sorting order of the list). I suggest using a key that extracts the last element from the tuple:

```
min(..., key=lambda b: b[2])
```

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Thanks for help:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list1 =[[1, 0, 2.83], [3, 1, 1.0], [5, 4, 2.83], [7, 0, 4.47], [6, 5, 4.24], [3, 2, 'x'], [4, 6, 'asd']]
min_val = min(filter(lambda x:not isinstance(x[-1], str), list1), key=lambda x:x[-1])
```

Output:

```
[3, 1, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this option:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list1 =[[1, 0, 2.83], [3, 1, 1.0], [5, 4, 2.83], [7, 0, 4.47], [6, 5, 4.24], [3, 2, 'x'], [4, 6, 'asd']]
>>> min((x for x in list1 if isinstance(x[-1], float)), key = itemgetter(-1))
[3, 1, 1.0]
```